# COPY 0 when copying table with data in PostgreSQL to CSV

Tags: postgresql

I have a table under a schema, `table_schema`, that has data in it:

```
\c data_store
select count(*) from table_schema.mytable;
9898123 rows
```

But when I try to copy this data to a CSV file, I get COPY 0:

```
copy table_schema.mytable to '/tmp/mytable.csv' with (format csv, header);
COPY 0
```

but if use a select instead, the file is created correctly:

```
copy (select * from table_schema.mytable) to '/tmp/mytable.csv' with (format csv, header)
COPY 9898123
```

Any ideas on what's going on here? PostgreSQL version is 9.6.

Comment: It is really a table not a view?

Comment: Yep, it's a table with child tables and views, but the table itself is not a view.

Comment: Are there any rows in table_schema.mytable or is all data in the child tables? COPY only returns row from the table specified, not from child tables.